# Ansible Lint isn't able to catch certain errors for the playbook tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-lint

name[missing] rule is not checked for the standalone playbook. however, its checked for the role though. here is an example ansible-playbook I tested and once I run ansible-lint, it says 'Passed with production profile: 0 failure(s), 0 warning(s) on 1 files' which means no error/warning found:

```yaml
---
- name: Update web servers
  hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.yum:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
    - ansible.builtin.template:
        src: /srv/httpd.j2
        dest: /etc/httpd.conf
```

as you can see, it doesn't have name in the task which should be caught while running ansible-lint. however, name[missing] works fine for roles.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest ansible-lint 6.11

```bash
shell> ansible-lint --version
ansible-lint 6.11.0 using ansible 2.14.1
```

Your playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yaml 
- name: Update web servers
  hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - ansible.builtin.yum:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
    - ansible.builtin.template:
        src: /srv/httpd.j2
        dest: /etc/httpd.conf
```

failed as expected

```bash
shell> ansible-lint playbook.yaml
WARNING  Listing 4 violation(s) that are fatal
name[missing]: All tasks should be named.
playbook.yaml:8 Task/Handler: yum name=httpd state=latest

package-latest: Package installs should not use latest.
playbook.yaml:8 Task/Handler: yum name=httpd state=latest

name[missing]: All tasks should be named.
playbook.yaml:11 Task/Handler: template src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf

risky-file-permissions: File permissions unset or incorrect. (warning)
playbook.yaml:11 Task/Handler: template src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf

You can skip specific rules or tags by adding them to your configuration file:
# .config/ansible-lint.yml
warn_list:  # or 'skip_list' to silence them completely
  - experimental  # all rules tagged as experimental
  - name[missing]  # Rule for checking task and play names.
  - package-latest  # Package installs should not use latest.

                            Rule Violation Summary                             
 count tag                    profile rule associated tags                     
     2 name[missing]          basic   idiom                                    
     1 package-latest         safety  idempotency                              
     1 risky-file-permissions safety  unpredictability, experimental (warning) 

Failed after min profile: 3 failure(s), 1 warning(s) on 1 files.
```

Comment: thank you for your response. but try with just 'ansible-lint' without passing the filename